# Removing quotes in file helpers

Tags: c#, filehelpers

I have a .csv file(I have no control over the data) and for some reason it has everything in quotes.

```
"Date","Description","Original Description","Amount","Type","Category","Name","Labels","Notes"
"2/02/2012","ac","ac","515.00","a","b","","javascript://"
"2/02/2012","test","test","40.00","a","d","c",""," "
```

I am using [filehelpers](http://www.filehelpers.com/) and I am wondering what the best way to remove all these quotes would be? Is there something that says "if I see quotes remove. If no quotes found do nothing"?

This messes with the data as I will have `"\"515.00\""` with unneeded extra quotes(especially since I want in this case it to be a decimal not a string".

I am also not sure what the "javascript" is all about and why it was generated but this is from a service I have no control over.

**edit**
this is how I consume the csv file.

```
    using (TextReader textReader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            engine.ErrorManager.ErrorMode = ErrorMode.SaveAndContinue; 

            object[] transactions = engine.ReadStream(textReader);
        }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `FieldQuoted` attribute described best on the attributes page [here](http://www.filehelpers.com/attributes.html).  Note that the attribute can be applied to any FileHelpers field (even if it type `Decimal`).  (Remember that the FileHelpers class describes the spec for your import file..  So when you mark a `Decimal` field as `FieldQuoted`, you are saying *in the file, this field will be quoted.*)

You can even specify whether or not the quotes are optional with

```
[FieldQuoted('"', QuoteMode.OptionalForBoth)]
```

Here is a console application which works with your data:

```
class Program
{
    [DelimitedRecord(",")]
    [IgnoreFirst(1)]
    public class Format1
    {
        [FieldQuoted]
        [FieldConverter(ConverterKind.Date, "d/M/yyyy")]
        public DateTime Date;
        [FieldQuoted]
        public string Description;
        [FieldQuoted]
        public string OriginalDescription;
        [FieldQuoted]
        public Decimal Amount;
        [FieldQuoted]
        public string Type;
        [FieldQuoted]
        public string Category;
        [FieldQuoted]
        public string Name;
        [FieldQuoted]
        public string Labels;
        [FieldQuoted]
        [FieldOptional]
        public string Notes;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var engine = new FileHelperEngine(typeof(Format1));

        // read in the data   
        object[] importedObjects = engine.ReadString(@"""Date"",""Description"",""Original Description"",""Amount"",""Type"",""Category"",""Name"",""Labels"",""Notes""
""2/02/2012"",""ac"",""ac"",""515.00"",""a"",""b"","""",""javascript://""
""2/02/2012"",""test"",""test"",""40.00"",""a"",""d"",""c"","""","" """);

        // check that 2 records were imported
        Assert.AreEqual(2, importedObjects.Length);

        // check the values for the first record
        Format1 customer1 = (Format1)importedObjects[0];
        Assert.AreEqual(DateTime.Parse("2/02/2012"), customer1.Date);
        Assert.AreEqual("ac", customer1.Description);
        Assert.AreEqual("ac", customer1.OriginalDescription);
        Assert.AreEqual(515.00, customer1.Amount);
        Assert.AreEqual("a", customer1.Type);
        Assert.AreEqual("b", customer1.Category);
        Assert.AreEqual("", customer1.Name);
        Assert.AreEqual("javascript://", customer1.Labels);
        Assert.AreEqual("", customer1.Notes);

        // check the values for the second record
        Format1 customer2 = (Format1)importedObjects[1];
        Assert.AreEqual(DateTime.Parse("2/02/2012"), customer2.Date);
        Assert.AreEqual("test", customer2.Description);
        Assert.AreEqual("test", customer2.OriginalDescription);
        Assert.AreEqual(40.00, customer2.Amount);
        Assert.AreEqual("a", customer2.Type);
        Assert.AreEqual("d", customer2.Category);
        Assert.AreEqual("c", customer2.Name);
        Assert.AreEqual("", customer2.Labels);
        Assert.AreEqual(" ", customer2.Notes);
    }
}
```

(Note, your first line of data seems to have 8 fields instead of 9, so I marked the `Notes` field with `FieldOptional`).

Answer (score 0):

Here’s one way of doing it:

```
string[] lines = new string[]
{
    "\"Date\",\"Description\",\"Original Description\",\"Amount\",\"Type\",\"Category\",\"Name\",\"Labels\",\"Notes\"",
    "\"2/02/2012\",\"ac\",\"ac\",\"515.00\",\"a\",\"b\",\"\",\"javascript://\"",
    "\"2/02/2012\",\"test\",\"test\",\"40.00\",\"a\",\"d\",\"c\",\"\",\" \"",
};

string[][] values =
    lines.Select(line =>
        line.Trim('"')
            .Split(new string[] { "\",\"" }, StringSplitOptions.None)
            .ToArray()
        ).ToArray();
```

The `lines` array represents the lines in your sample. Each `"` character must be escaped as `\"` in C# string literals.

For each line, we start off by removing the first and last `"` characters, then proceed to split it into a collection of substrings, using the `","` character sequence as the delimiter.

Note that the above code will **not work** if you have `"` characters occurring naturally within your values (even if escaped).

**Edit**: If your CSV is to be read from a stream, all your need to do is:

```
var lines = new List<string>();
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(stream))
    while (!streamReader.EndOfStream)
        lines.Add(streamReader.ReadLine());
```

The rest of the above code would work intact.

**Edit**: Given your new code, check whether you’re looking for something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < transactions.Length; ++i)
{
    object oTrans = transactions[i]; 
    string sTrans = oTrans as string;
    if (sTrans != null && 
        sTrans.StartsWith("\"") &&
        sTrans.EndsWith("\""))
    {
        transactions[i] = sTrans.Substring(1, sTrans.Length - 2);
    }
}
```

Comment: The code I gave is an example from a .csv file that gets uploaded and read from a stream.

Comment: Well they got some build method "engine" that returns a array of objects. See changes.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same predicament and I replace the quotes when I load the value into my list object:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication6
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LoadCSV();
        }

        private void LoadCSV()
        {
            List<string> Rows = new List<string>();
            string m_CSVFilePath = "<Path to CSV File>";

            using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(m_CSVFilePath))
            {
                string row;

                while ((row = r.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    Rows.Add(row.Replace("\"", ""));
                }

                foreach (var Row in Rows)
                {
                    if (Row.Length > 0)
                    {
                        string[] RowValue = Row.Split(',');

                        //Do something with values here
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I been looking into the options and seems like this field attribute might do the trick. FieldQuoted(QuoteMode.OptionalForBoth). I think they are missing one option though(one that would just ignore quotes on both read and write)

Comment: @chobo2 - That's fine but if you use Filehelpers you still need to install a dll on the client machine right? My solution just uses the Framework with no need for any additional files.

Answer (score 0):

This code might help which I developed:

```
using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader("C:\\Projects\\Mactive\\Audience\\DrawBalancing\\CSVFiles\\Analytix_ABC_HD.csv"))
{
     string row;

     int outCount;
         StringBuilder line=new StringBuilder() ;
         string token="";
         char chr;
         string Eachline;

     while ((row = r.ReadLine()) != null)
     {
         outCount = row.Length;
         line = new StringBuilder();
         for (int innerCount = 0; innerCount <= outCount - 1; innerCount++)
         {                   
             chr=row[innerCount];

             if (chr != '"')
             {
                 line.Append(row[innerCount].ToString());
             }
             else if(chr=='"')
             {
                 token = "";
                 innerCount = innerCount + 1;
                 for (; innerCount < outCount - 1; innerCount++)
                 {
                     chr=row[innerCount];
                     if(chr=='"')
                     {
                         break;
                     }

                     token = token + chr.ToString();                               
                 }

                 if(token.Contains(",")){token=token.Replace(",","");}
                 line.Append(token);
             }                 
         }
         Eachline = line.ToString();
         Console.WriteLine(Eachline);
    }
}
```